# Specific users can only see and fill in specific fields in a sharepoint list

Tags: list, permissions

I'm pretty new to sharepoint.  I want to know how to create list fields that can only be seen by some people, and edited by other people.

Is it possible to attach permission groups to list fields or does this have to be achieved another way?

Comment: what version of sharepoint using?

Comment: Sharepoint server 2010

Answer (score 0):

Ww had this problem a month ago.
If these list fields are lookup fields, then you can set permissions to the lookup field.
If there aren't, well, there two solutions:

a) use kwizcom field permission : http://www.kwizcom.com/sharepoint-add-ons/sharepoint-field-permissions/overview/

b) use jquery to hide fields, accoarding to the SP group the user belongs to. I could attach the code - I'm not in the office.